# how to inner join the third column that need to use the function of count

Tags: sql, count

```
select distinct CatalogNo_No.branch_id, dvd.DVD_name from

CatalogNo_No inner join DVD on CatalogNo_No.DVD_catalogno = DVD.DVD_catalogno
inner join count (catalogno_no.branch_id='MA0001',catalogno_no.branch_id='MA0002',catalogno_no.branch_id='MA0003',catalogno_no.branch_id='MA0004',catalogno_no.branch_id='MA0005')

where catalogno_no.DVD_catalogno in (select DVD_catalogno from DVD where DVD_name='Final Destination')
```

the out put I want is distinct CatalogNo_No.branch_id, dvd.DVD_name and CatalogNo_No.branch_id count of the branch_id without distinct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`

```
select
  CatalogNo_No.branch_id,
  dvd.DVD_name,
  count(*) branch_count
from CatalogNo_No
join DVD on CatalogNo_No.DVD_catalogno = DVD.DVD_catalogno
where catalogno_no.DVD_catalogno in (select DVD_catalogno from DVD where DVD_name='Final Destination')
  and catalogno_no.branch_id in ('MA0001','MA0002','MA0003','MA0004','MA0005')
group by CatalogNo_No.branch_id, dvd.DVD_name
```

Comment: but it will become 5 extra column can I done it all in 1 column?

Comment: sorry, May I add your skype ? I have some similar problem like this question but I need to screenshot it for you idk how to explain